# Not returning children from XML in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, loops, nodes

I'm retreiving XML from an api and using PHP to drop it into a nice ordered array..

Basically it's for a category menu, returning 3 levels of categories that will go into a 3-tier bulleted list.

The first level had a node name of 'CustomCategory', within this there's a child node called 'ChildCategory'.  This is perfect I can loop within the first and echo out the second level.

The problem is that within the second level, the third level node is also called 'ChildCategory'.

It looks a bit like this:

```
<CustomCategories>
    <CustomCategory>
          <Name>Category 1</Name>
          <ChildCategory>
               <Name>Child 1</Name>
               <ChildCategory>
                    <Name>Child 1a</Name>
               </ChildCategory>
          <ChildCategory>
            <Name>Child 2</Name>
          </ChildCategory>
    </CustomCategory>
    <CustomCategory>
          <Name>Category 2</Name>
    </CustomCategory>
</CustomCategories>
```

This means that when i'm looping through the first level to get the children, it's not just looking at the second level, it's going through each of the third level in turn as it's the same node name...

How can I run my second loop but ignore the children?

This is my code at the moment:

```
$responseDoc = new DomDocument();
$responseDoc->loadXML($responseXml);

$categories=[];

// loop level 1
foreach ($responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('CustomCategory') as $cat1) {  

          $Name1 = $cat1->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item(0)->nodeValue; 
          $cats1['name1'] = $Name1;

          // loop level 2
          foreach ($cat1->getElementsByTagName('ChildCategory') as $cat2) {

               $Name2 = $cat2->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
               $cats2['name2'] = $Name2;
               $cats1['subcat']= $cats2;

          }

          $categories[] = $cats1;

}
```

NB: It's a little stripped down as I'm doing some funky stuff in how the arrays get ordered as they go in.

at the moment when I echo this out, it creates a list, with all the 2nd/3rd level together in one.

I want to out put the data in the end like this:

The values I need to get at the name, so I can put them into an array and echo out such as :

```
<ul>
    <li>Category 1
        <ul>
            <li>Child1
                <ul>
                    <li>Child 1a</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category 1</li>
</ul>
```

However the 3rd tier children come out in the second loop....

Many thanks!

Comment: Provide one more main `<CustomCategory>` node inside `<CustomCategories>` & mention what values you need to get. The given XML is not valid.

Comment: It looks valid to me (though i left off a slack on the last but one line...  I will add this now.  why would you need a third?  I can add this though..?

the values i look for I will add to question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMNode::getElementsByTagName()` returns all descendant element nodes with that name. You could iterate the `$childNodes` property and validate each node type and name or you use Xpath.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/CustomCategories/CustomCategory') as $customCategory) {
  echo $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $customCategory), "\n";
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('ChildCategory', $customCategory) as $childCategory) {
    echo ' -> ',  $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $childCategory), "\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Category 1
 -> Child 1
 -> Child 2
Category 2
```

You mention that you need to order the categories. An easy way to do this is converting the node list into an array and use a custom sort.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$customCategories = iterator_to_array(
   $xpath->evaluate('/CustomCategories/CustomCategory')
);
// sort the categories by name, descending
uasort(
  $customCategories,
  function($one, $two) use ($xpath) {
    return -1 * strcasecmp(
      $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $one),
      $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $two)
    );
  }
);

foreach ($customCategories as $customCategory) {
  echo $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $customCategory), "\n";
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('ChildCategory', $customCategory) as $childCategory) {
    echo ' -> ',  $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $childCategory), "\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Category 2
Category 1
 -> Child 1
 -> Child 2
```